# Derivative of trace

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, operator-theory

Consider two positive-semi definite matrices $T_1, T_2$ of unit trace.

Let $T(\lambda):=T_1 + \lambda(T_2-T_1)$ be the convex combination of the two.

We then study $f(\lambda) := \operatorname{tr}(T(\lambda)\log(T(\lambda))).$

I conjecture that $f'(\lambda) = \operatorname{tr}(P_{\operatorname{ker}(T_1)} T_2)\log(\lambda)+\mathcal O(1),$ for $\lambda>0$ small, where $P_V$ is the orthogonal projection on the space $V$.

I actually did not want to use the spectral theorem to show this but e.g. go via Jacobi's formula

$$e^{ \operatorname{tr}(T(\lambda)\log(T(\lambda))} = \operatorname{det}(e^{T(\lambda)\log(T(\lambda))}).$$

Are there any elementary proofs of this? Or is my conjecture even wrong?

Comment: $T\log T$ need not be trace class.

Comment: @ChristianRemling let us assume that this is the case for all lambda we consider, or better let us work with matrices :)

Comment: What assumption do you make so that ln T(λ) exists? Taking T1=T2 to be any positive sem-definite matrix with 0 as an eigenvalue shows that ln T(λ) does not exist in general.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was for the original conjecture in the OP (before the edits). I'm leaving it for the record.

<sub>To test the conjectured formula, let me take a simple case of diagonal $2\times 2$ matrices, $T_1=\text{diag}(1,0)$, $T_2=\text{diag}(0,1)$, both positive semi-definite and of unit trace; then 
$$f(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)\log(1-\lambda)+\lambda\log\lambda$$
$$\Rightarrow f'(\lambda)=\log\lambda-\log(1-\lambda).$$ 
The conjectured formula would give $f'(\lambda)=\log\lambda+{\cal O}(1)$, which fails when $\lambda$ approaches 1.</sub>

Comment: sorry, this formula was indeed only thought to capture the singularity, so $\lambda$ close to zero.